# Is there a download option for the documentation and tutorials at https://perldoc.perl.org/5.30.0? (Windows user)

Tags: windows, download, perl, documentation, man

I want the documentation and probably the tutorials saved locally on my computer, as usually I only have a 64 kbit/s internet connection. I'm working on Windows 10.

At [perlfaq1.html#AUTHOR-AND-COPYRIGHT](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.30.0/perlfaq1.html#AUTHOR-AND-COPYRIGHT) it says

> This documentation is free; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
>   under the same terms as Perl itself.

Is there an archive file to download especially the documentation and maybe the tutorials? Or would I have to download them file by file?

Answer (score 0):

You can download perldoc entire PerlDoc site here: [https://github.com/OpusVL/perldoc.perl.org-export](https://github.com/OpusVL/perldoc.perl.org-export/archive/master.zip)

Or get [just the 5.30 docs here](https://github.com/OpusVL/perldoc.perl.org-export).